# How to do simple http redirect using Python?

Tags: python, http, redirect, header

How to do simple http redirect using Python? *without using meta*.

#### UPDATE:

I am using Python 2.7.1 as a CGI from within the cgi-bin directory of Apache.

Comment: This depends entirely on what web framework you're using.

Comment: for http redirect you should output header with content **location: newUrl** to the client. To send headers, use appropriate function on your framework.

Comment: I am using Python as a CGI script from within the cgi-bin directory of apache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To redirect using your current setup (CGI apache):

```
print("Location:http://newurl.com/foobar")
print # to end the CGI response headers.
```

Comment: am getting a "Premature end of script headers" error.  The print statement is my first line after #!/Python27/python.

Comment: The url of browser(Chrome) seems not change

Comment: While this works fine in Chrome on my desktop, on my ipad get a safari error saying "too many redirects"... any ideas? I tried emptying the cache on the ipad.. but no luck.