# Two different actions for HTML form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect

I'm trying to write an HTML file that does the following:
It takes one set of form fields with a common name, and submits them to a file "delete.py", and then it takes a different set of form fields and submits those values to a "test.pl" file. This all happens when I hit the submit button. 
I don't want to to be redirected to the "delete.py" page, but I do want to be redirected to the "test.pl" page on submit.

Is this possible? How can I do this?

If this is too complicated, what I was thinking was making the delete.py into an intermediate redirection page, that carries forth the post values meant to be sent to the test.pl page. I wouldn't know how to redirect the post values though, so If someone thinks that this works out better, I would appreciate knowing how to redirect the post values.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can either:

Submit to an `iframe`, using the `target` attribute of the form.

...or you can submit using AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

You could have `delete.py` execute some code and then do a header redirect to `test.pl` as long as your `delete.py` doesn't write anything out to the page.

Here is how to do the header redirect:

```
Status: 302 Temporarily moved
Location: http://some.org/new-URL.html
```

In Python, at the end of your script:

```
print("Status: 302 Temporarily moved")
print("Location:http://some.org/new-URL.html")
print # to end the CGI response headers.
```

Make sure you don't have any other output prior to this on that page.

[Reference Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320916/how-to-do-simple-http-redirect-using-python)

Comment: Can you give me more details of how that would look in the delete.py file? Like would I print that header data instead of "Content-type: text/html\n\n...etc" ?, also will this carry on the post request values sent to the test.pl page?

Comment: Yes it will carry over.  Your browser will actually send the same request to the new location you're redirecting to.  I updated the answer with what I believe is the correct syntax for doing this in Python.

Comment: I got back to this project, and it isn't forwarding the post request data as it should. Ideas?