# How to execute another python program when some condition is met?

Tags: python, html

```
This is validate.py

import cgi
import yate
import sqlite3


connection = sqlite3.connect('users.sqlite')
cursor = connection.cursor()

print(yate.start_response('text/plain'))
form=cgi.FieldStorage()
for each_form_item in form.keys():
  if (each_form_item=='username'):
    username=form[each_form_item].value
  if (each_form_item=='password'):
    password=form[each_form_item].value

result=cursor.execute('SELECT USERNAME from validate')
usernames=[row[0] for row in result.fetchall()]
for each_username in usernames:
    if (username==each_username):
        pass_result=cursor.execute('SELECT PASSWORD from validate where username=?',(each_username,))
    password1=[row[0] for row in pass_result.fetchall()]
    for each_password in password1:
        if (each_password==password):
            print('Login Success')
           #Here want to run another python program eg welcome.py
        else:
            print('Login Failure')
```

The web server is running in the background. I want to webpage to redirect to another python program if the condition in the above code is true. How do I do that?

EDIT:

Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Login Page</title>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="coach.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <img src="images/logo-cel-transparent_0.png" width="74" height="64">      <strong><img src="images/logo-cel-transparent_0.png"  alt="Cel logo" width="74" height="64" align="right">
     </strong>
     <h1 align="center"><strong>Central Electronics Limited</strong></h1>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <h2 align="center">Storage Management System</h2>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
       <p align="center">Login to System</p>
     <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
     <form action="/cgi-bin/validate.py" method="post">
    <div align="center">User name :
     <input type="text" name="username" value=""> <br>
       Password : <input type="text" name="password" value="">  <br>
     <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
     </div>
     </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

When i click on the submit button validate.py runs. Now if the username and password match, I want the web browser to automatically redirect the browser to another py file or html page, without the user needing to do anything.

EDIT2:

I am using a python server whose code is:

```
  from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

  port = 8080

   httpd = HTTPServer(('', port), CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
   print("Starting simple_httpd on port: " + str(httpd.server_port))
   httpd.serve_forever()
```

This is run using command prompt. The index page i then open in web browser using "localhost:8080".

Comment: I suspect that you don't really want to spawn an entirely new Python process, but maybe just spawn a new thread.

Comment: I have no idea what you said, but basically i just want to redirect the page to a new html page or a python program. Is any of the two possible?

Comment: Redirect who? How is this run? And how is the user accessing it? Is that the complete code?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and helping out. I'll tell in detail. No that is not the complete code. Initially, we have an html page called index.html whose code i am posting below.

Comment: I posted that in the edit, please see above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`execfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) command this way:

```py
for each_username in usernames:
    if (username==each_username):
        pass_result=cursor.execute('SELECT PASSWORD from validate where username=?',(each_username,))
    password1=[row[0] for row in pass_result.fetchall()]
    for each_password in password1:
        if (each_password==password):
            print('Login Success')
            execfile(PATH_TO_THE_FILE+"./welcome.py")
        else:
            print('Login Failure')
```

Note: `PATH_TO_THE_FILE` is the path in your disk and it should be a string

**EDIT**

As you are using python 3x, here is the alternative of `execfile` command:

```py
with open("welcome.py") as f:
    code = compile(f.read(), "welcome.py", 'exec')
    exec(code)
```

Comment: It gives NameError execfile not defined. Probably becuase i am using Python 3.4?

Comment: Just on a side note, is it possible to use the execfile command for an html page?

Comment: @ShivamAgarwal I am not sure but I don't think so

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Python [subprocesses?](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)

Comment: Yes i have but it displays an error message: access is denied

Comment: \r\n    subprocess.call(\'C:\\Python34\\ProjectShivam\\webapp\\cgi-bin\')\r
\n  File "C:\\Python34\\lib\\subprocess.py", line 537, in call\r\n    with Popen
(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:\r\n  File "C:\\Python34\\lib\\subprocess.py", line
859, in __init__\r\n    restore_signals, start_new_session)\r\n  File "C:\\Pytho
n34\\lib\\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child\r\n    startupinfo)\r\nPe
rmissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied\r\n'
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jun/2015 00:16:00] CGI script exit status 0x1

Comment: Where is the script you're trying to execute located? Try running the parent process as an administrator.

Comment: Sorry sir but that went over my head

Answer (score 0):

Instead of spawning a subprocess, you could create a method in your other Python file that takes a page as an argument. You could then import that method into the file you have posted.

In the file you want to call "file.py":

```
def start(page):
    do_something()
```

And now:

```
from file import start

for each_username in usernames:
    if (username==each_username):
        pass_result=cursor.execute('SELECT PASSWORD from validate where username=?',(each_username,))
password1=[row[0] for row in pass_result.fetchall()]
for each_password in password1:
    if (each_password==password):
        print('Login Success')
       start(some_page)
    else:
        print('Login Failure')
```

Answer (score 0):

So it appears you want to redirect the user from inside a CGI script to process a POST request. Well, to do that, set the `Location` header. It appears you are using a library to print all headers, but you will need to change that.

As demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320916/how-to-do-simple-http-redirect-using-python), this can look something like this:

```
import cgi
import yate
import sqlite3


connection = sqlite3.connect('users.sqlite')
cursor = connection.cursor()



form=cgi.FieldStorage()
for each_form_item in form.keys():
  if (each_form_item=='username'):
    username=form[each_form_item].value
  if (each_form_item=='password'):
    password=form[each_form_item].value

result=cursor.execute('SELECT USERNAME from validate')
usernames=[row[0] for row in result.fetchall()]
for each_username in usernames:
    if (username==each_username):
        pass_result=cursor.execute('SELECT PASSWORD from validate where username=?',(each_username,))
    password1=[row[0] for row in pass_result.fetchall()]
    for each_password in password1:
        if (each_password==password):
            print('Location:your/new/url')
        else:
            print('Content-type:text/plain')
            print('')
            print('Login Failure')
```

Comment: I did that, but it printed the Location in plain text in the browser. It did not redirect it!  Also please see the edit in the question, I am using a python inbuilt server.

Comment: Did you make sure you had not already sent a blank line after previous headers?

Comment: Yes! The location was the first print statement in the whole validation.py program.

Comment: I edited my answer, I may have mistaken. Please try the code as it is now. On a side note, you should look into using a web framework like django. That will make things a lot easier!

Comment: It shows a blank page and the url doesnt change. But thanks for helping! And i'll look into django. Hope that doesn't go over my head. :)