# OS Error : Error No 22

Tags: python, cgi

This is the error :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jun/2015 17:15:21] "POST /cgi-bin/get_tran_data.py HTTP/1.1" 2
00 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jun/2015 17:15:21] command: C:\Python34\python.exe -u C:\Pytho
n34\ProjectShivam\webapp\cgi-bin\get_tran_data.py ""
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jun/2015 17:15:22] b'Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  F
ile "C:\\Python34\\ProjectShivam\\webapp\\cgi-bin\\get_tran_data.py", line 20, i
n <module>\r\n    with open("C:\\Python34\\ProjectShivam\\webapp\\cgi-bin\\tran_
add_success.py") as g:\r\nOSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: \'C:\\\\Python34
\\\\ProjectShivam\\\\webapp\\\\cgi-bin\\tran_add_success.py\'\r\n'
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jun/2015 17:15:22] CGI script exit status 0x1
```

get_tran_data.py:

```
import cgi
import yate
import sqlite3
import sys

connection = sqlite3.connect('users.sqlite')
cursor = connection.cursor()
print('Content-type:text/html')
form=cgi.FieldStorage()
doctype=form['doctype'].value
docno=form['docno'].value
docdate=form['docdate'].value
bincard=form['bincard'].value
rate=form['rate'].value
quantity=form['qty'].value

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TRAN(DOCTYPE,DOCNO,DOCDATE,BINCARD,QTY,RATE) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",(doctype,docno,docdate,bincard,rate,quantity))
connection.commit()

with open("C:\Python34\ProjectShivam\webapp\cgi-bin\tran_add_success.py") as g:
                code = compile(g.read(),"tran_add_success.py", 'exec')
                exec(code)
```

When i remove the open statement from get_tran_data.py, the script runs successfully. I used a similar open statement in another script and that ran successfully but here i don't know what is the problem?

EDIT:

This is get_opb_data.py, the script with similar code but runs successfully:

```
import cgi
import yate
import sqlite3
import sys

connection = sqlite3.connect('users.sqlite')
cursor = connection.cursor()
print('Content-type:text/html')
form=cgi.FieldStorage()
bincard=form['bincard'].value
desc=form['desc'].value
loc=form['loc'].value
qty=form['qty'].value
rate=form['rate'].value
Value=form['value'].value
currate=form['currate'].value
curqty=form['curqty'].value

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO OPB(Bincard,Description,Location,Quantity,Rate,Value,CurRate,CurQty) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(bincard,desc,loc,qty,rate,Value,currate,curqty))
connection.commit()

with open("C:\Python34\ProjectShivam\webapp\cgi-bin\opb_add_success.py") as f:
                code = compile(f.read(), "opb_add_success.py", 'exec')
                exec(code)
```

Also, the tran_add_success.py file exists, I have made sure of that. I don't get why this is happening, that once script is running just fine and the other isnt.

tran.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Transaction</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="coach.css" />
</head>
<body>
<img src="images/logo-cel-transparent_0.png" width="74" height="64"><strong><img src="images/logo-cel-transparent_0.png" alt="Cel logo" width="74" height="64" align="right">
</strong>
<h1 align="center"><strong>Central Electronics Limited</strong></h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h2 align="center">Storage Management System</h2>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div align="center"><strong>Transaction!!</strong></div>
<p align="left">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">
<form action="cgi-bin/get_tran_data.py" method="post">
  <div align="center">DocType &nbsp;:&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="doctype">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    DocNo :
    <input type="text" name="docno">
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     DocDate :
    <input type="text" name="docdate">
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <br><br>

     BinCard :
    <input type="text" name="bincard">
     &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
     Rate : &nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="rate">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     Quantity : 
    <input type="text" name="qty">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <br>
    <p align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
  </div>
</form>

</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When i click the submit button on tran.html, the get_tran_data.py runs. Now it fetches the data from the form and saves it to database. I use open statement in get_tran_data.py so as to run another script which displays a success message on the screen.

Comment: Most likely that the file doesn't exist. But why use an `open` and `exec` statement to run Python code in another file in the same directory, instead of an `import` statement?

Comment: As `[Errno 22] Invalid argument: \'C:\\\\Python34
\\\\ProjectShivam\\\\webapp\\\\cgi-bin\\tran_add_success.py\'\r\n'` shows, your path does not seemt to be a valid pathname. Make sure file exists and if so try to use `os.path.join` to provide path in a 'more valid' format...

Comment: @DavidRobinson The file exists I made sure. I used an open statement because, refer to this please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673475/how-to-execute-another-python-program-when-some-condition-is-met

Comment: @albert Please see the edit I made. The file exists I made sure. Could you elaborate on the os.path.join usage please?

Comment: @ShivamAgarwal: [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) combines different parts of a path by using exactly one path-separator. I am absolutely not sure, but this could prevent these several backslashes in your error message due to a possibly malformatted path.